# Como verificar opção de radio button e mostrar tabela HTML correspondente

Tags: javascript, php, html

Situação: Temos três tabelas no mesmo formulário a primeira contém o radio button:

```
<td> <input required="required"
 value="Evento" name="tipo" id="evento" type="radio">
<label for="tipo">Evento.</label> <input required="required" value="Viagem" name="tipo" id="viagem" type="radio">
<label for="tipo">Viagem</label></td>
```

No momento é mostrada as duas tabelas na tela, quero que seja mostrada apenas uma que depende da escolha.
Como poderia ser feito o `if` para mostrar determinada tabela?
Por exemplo

if (código){
tabela sobre viagens
}

if(outrocódigo){
tabela sobre eventos
}

É possível fazer por PHP ou tem que ser Javascript?

Já tentei
    `<?php if($_POST['tipo']=='evento') : ?>
    tabela em HTML que eu quero mostrar
    <?php endif; ?>`
mas me dá o erro:
*Undefined index: tipo*

Comment: Vinicios pode colocar o codigo completo dentro do if? E já agora, antes do IF a tag de php está aberta?

Comment: @Sergio O código completo é muito extenso mas é uma tabela `<table>` em HTML cheio de inputs e o action button. a tag php estava aberta sim. Pergunta corrigida. Obrigado,

Comment: Ok, agora parece-me que está a abrir a tag `<?php` duas vezes, a segunda no `endif`

Comment: Oops corrigi mais uma vez faltou `: ?>` na pergunta. Fiz dessa maneira pois assim o HTML da <table> pode ser executado, a dúvida agora é como passar o valor da escolha do radio button para uma variável? Poderia ser, assim fazer a comparação e mostrar a segunda ou terceira tabela corretamente.

Comment: Se o radio button fôr mudado/clicado pelo utilizador então tem de ser com javascript. É esse o seu caso?

Comment: Sim é esse! Então não tem como fazer com PHP em um if?
Como eu poderia fazer usando Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function () {
    $('.tabelaextra').addClass('escondida')
    $('#t' + this.id).removeClass('escondida');
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/9u5yx/1/)

Neste exemplo fiz:

- adicionei uma classe escondida para as tabelas estarem escondidas quando a página abre
- adicionei uma classe tabelaextra para ser mais fácil ter um selector que as encontre
- dei às novas tabelas um id e vou procurá-la concatenando o id do radio button para remover a classe escondida
- esta solução usa jQuery

Se precisar de uma solução só com javascript puro, pode usar **[esta (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/yDpP4/)**.

Comment: A parte de CSS eu preciso colocar necessariamente em um arquivo style.css e declarar na página?

Comment: @Vinicius, idealmente num ficheiro à parte. Se a pagina fica grande depois é fácil esquecer que aquele código está na página em vez do ficheiro CSS. Mas sim, funciona também se estiver na página, dentro da tag `<head>` e dentro de tags `<style>`: http://jsfiddle.net/9u5yx/2/

Comment: Com o Jquery não fui muito bem Mas com o Javascript TIVE progresso, agora ele esconde as duas ultimas tabelas mas ao clicar ele abre a tabela selecionada ao trocar para o outro radio button ele abre a outra tabela e fica nisso as duas tabelas abertas independente de qual radio button se da o clique.
Não consigo encontrar o meu erro, aonde eu coloco o Javascript?

Comment: @Vinicius, tem algum erro no javascript? (na consola) Em relação a onde colocar, pode pôr no fim da página antes do `</body>` e dentro de tags `<script>`. No exemplo funciona como você quer?

Comment: Por Javascript funcionou! colocando o código javascript  depois de todas as tabelas.
Como se colocaria o Jquery? Pois aqui eu não consegui gerar ação com ele.

Enfim.
Muito Obrigado @Sergio

Comment: @Vinicius, para usar jQuery (que é javascript) é preciso carregar biblioteca usando o script (tags incluídas) que se __[encontra aqui](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)__. Porém se não precisa, javascript puro é suficiente.

Comment: Encontrei uma inconsistência somente agora... Esse método pode estar quebrando o action do form? Pois há campos obrigatórios em todas as tabelas no entanto o action só é ativado quando eu preencho todos os campos obrigatórios, o objetivo @Sergio também é desativar/remover a tabela não escolhida. Para o utilizador enviar somente os dados da tabela principal e da tabela escolhida (viagem ou evento). Esse código não faz isso correto? Como poderia ser feito? Desde já. Obrigado.

Comment: @Vinicius, hmmm assim fica um pouco mais complexo. Que validate utiliza? Teste esta idea: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZdZf/

Comment: Em Jquery não carrega nenhuma nem outra, como ficaria no javascript puro?

Comment: @Vinicius, já experimentou a adicionar o script do jQuery no head da página? em javascript puro fica muito código e duvido conseguir fazer isso hoje ainda. Já agora se tiver um link online dá para testar melhor o problema.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`
Esta na tag head da página. É isso?

Comment: Eu também pensei numa coisa assim (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2688627)
com alguma coisa a mais pra voltar a ativar as tabelas pois ao selecionar a opção ele abre mas ao selecionar outra opção ele fecha a tabela e não volta mais com a outra.

Comment: @Vinicius, acerca do jQuery sim, mas só o segundo link. O primeiro link pode ignorar, a não ser que você precise dele. Em relação à segunda ideia parece-me agressiva. Nesse caso melhor usar AJAX e carregar a tabela.

Comment: To quase desistindo... Transformando as duas tabelas em duas paginas diferentes, fazendo um botão de próximo na tabela principal e dependendo da escolha se muda o action para determinada pagina com a tabela. E ai eu carrego os dados da tabela principal  manualmente com `$_POST` Mais simples não é mesmo? Como eu poderia mudar o action do form ao clicar no radio button? Desde já. Obrigado pela imensa paciência.

Comment: @Vinicius existe um link onde possa ver a página online? Existem muitas maneiras diferentes e é dificil prever tudo :) Se ambas as tabelas estão dentro do mesmo form então passam para o PHP. Só se estiverem disabled é que não.

Comment: Segue link.
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn435ewy45ftzrh/solic_recursos.php

Note que eu troquei os nomes das variáveis e classes pra entender melhor o funcionamento do código. Obrigado.

Comment: @Vinicius, o código assim funciona. A unica coisa errada e que eu não reparei antes é o seu link do jQuery. Você está a usar jQuery-ui, mas não é o `ui` que você quer, é este: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` => Versão ao vivo: __http://jsfiddle.net/Svd8D/__

Comment: Sim agora o código Jquery funcionou porém ele não remove a tabela realmente pois o action button ainda não funciona. Ele só funciona se eu voltar na outra tabela que eu não selecionei e preencher os campos obrigatórios.